# How to access table when the name is a keyword

Tags: mysql

I just realized that i assigned a table name as "AS" and when i was trying to do a select query, i kept getting an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"as"'.
```

So i looked up for reserved words and found out that "AS" is reserved. Well, i think i knew before (used for aliases) but just didn't consider it.

So to fix this will easily be to rename the table name. But assuming i don't want to, can i still access this table using some sort of symbol ? i tried putting it in quotes and double quotes but no success.

Comment: The 2 answers below are both fine, but I would advise you to change it now if you possibly can. Otherwise you will be having this error every time you touch that table for years!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mysql, you can wrap reserved words (or any words for that matter) in backticks to cause word to be parsed as a literal name rather than the keyword:

```
select * from `AS`
```

Read more about it in the [on line documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) under "identifier quote character".

Answer (score 1):

Yes use this(backtiks):

```
SELECT * FROM `as`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use backticks. Else MySQL will consider it as a Keyword. If we use backtick then they are called quoted identifiers and they tell the parser to handle the text between them as a literal string. They are useful for when you have a column or table that contains a keyword or space.

Please refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html